# Нет смены картинок при применении цикла с таймером в WPF. C#

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, время

В Microsoft Visual Studio, в WPF у меня лежат картинки, которые должны начать выводится кликом на кнопку.
Я написал таймер, который считает 1 секунду и следом выводит картинку.
Сверху написал цикл фор на 5 циклов. Но в итоге программа выводит не 5 картинок друг за другом с интервалом в 1 секунду, а последнюю.
Очевидно, он прогоняет цикл внутри без отображения предыдущих результатов. Как это исправить?

```
public void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    { 
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        stopWatch.Stop();

        Result2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Numbers/" + k.ToString() + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        k++;
    }
```